# My Carrot Apple Zucchini Bread is moist but it crumble when you cut it. How can I fix it?

Tags: bread, zucchini

I have been baking zucchini bread for many years. I bake several different kinds. I found this new recipe and decided to try it. It is moist and tastes great. The problem is when I cut a piece it crumbles. So you can't hold it and eat it like a piece of bread. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without a recipe.

Comment: Sorry forgot that part.

Comment: The recipe is.     1-cup butter

Comment: Sorry my tablet is acting weird. 1-cup butter, 2- cups sugar, 3- eggs,  1/4 cup orange juice, 1 Tbl. Vanilla,  3 1/4 cups flour,  1/2 tsp. Salt, 2 1/2  tsp. baking powder,  3/4 tsp. Baking soda,  1 tsp. Cinnamon,  1 cup shredded carrots, 2 cups shredded zucchini. I'm sorry for the format of the recipe as I said my tablet seems to have a mind of its own.

Comment: I forgot the recipe also calls for 1-cup of peeled and diced apple (any kind you want) can't believe I forgot to write down the apple it's in the name of the recipe 

Comment: You are more likely to get answers if edit the *question* to include both the ingredients and your method.

Comment: Having looked at a recipe which seems to be the same as yours and compared it with some others I can see two possibilities, the sugar content seems high. Many people commenting on the recipe said they cut the sugar way back. Another issue could be if you don’t wring enough water from the courgettes, the steam from those could push the structure apart in baking.